# Searching for 2 variables in several files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find 2 values in several textbased files.
The code i have is:

```
def newbat():
query1 = "Dump/data/log/batterystats/newbatterystats*"
name1 = "plug=ac"
strt = "RESET"
dus = os.path.join(path, query1)
entries1 = glob.glob(dus, recursive=True)
for entry in entries1:
    with open(entry, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if name1 in line:
                outs3 = os.path.join(path, 'newbatterystat.txt')
                sys.stdout = open(outs3, 'a')
                print(entry + '\n', line)
```

The name1 variable works.
If I replace name1 to strt it works.
I cannot find out how to use both variables, so the output file is:
RESET:TIME: 01-01-1970 plug=ac

Comment: Are you looking for lines that contain both of those strings? Could you use a regular expression? Also, out of interest, why Python, rather than grep?

Comment: If name1 in line and strt in line?…

Comment: Hi, i want to learn Python, so I am trying to do this the pythonic way. I know how to use grep and create bash script, but that's not the challenge.

Comment: @Sayse, no sorry, didn' t work. Thanks.

Comment: To be more specific, each file contains 1 RESET word, but multiple plug=ac words.

Comment: you probably need : `if (name1 in line) and (strt in line): ... `

Comment: @Jupri, No sorry, didn' t work. Thanks.

Comment: “Didn’t work” means nothing, how did the result(s) differ from your expectations

Comment: There was no output file, but also no fault comment in PyCharm. Using commandline neither.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to solve your problem, I would recommend you to use `regex`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = 'RESET:TIME: 01-01-1970 plug=ac'
>>> re.findall('(RESET|plug=ac)', text)
['RESET', 'plug=ac']
```

Comment: This would only give back the words, not the full line containing the words

Comment: @thamuppet - This will return an empty `list` if there is no expected string. You can use this in a `loop` by inserting a line from the text file into the `text` variable and checking if the `list` is `NOT` empty. BTW, I understood that's some challenge because from @fritsimeel side an simple algorithm could be written in `bash`...

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex really.

I would do something like this for each file you need to search in.

First example if both words has to be in the line. Second example if one word of a list of words has to be in line.

```
fruits = """1. orange, pear
2. banana, apple
3. pear, apple
4. apple, banana
5. banana, orange"""

fruits_split = fruits.split('\n')

print('First example:')
for line in fruits_split:
    if 'apple' in line and 'banana' in line:
        print(line)

my_fruits = ['apple', 'banana']
print('\nSecond example:')

for line in fruits_split:
    if any(x in line for x in my_fruits):
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
First example:
2. banana, apple
4. apple, banana

Second example:
2. banana, apple
3. pear, apple
4. apple, banana
5. banana, orange
```

Comment: Well, it gives me an output, but the second example returns every line from every file. The first example returns no output file. Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to help you further when you don't provide your output.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it, but not the most elegant way.

```
def newbat():
    query1 = "Dump/data/log/batterystats/newbatterystats*"
    name1 = 'plug=ac'
    strt = 'RESET:TIME'
    dus = os.path.join(path, query1)
    entries1 = glob.glob(dus, recursive=True)
    for entry in entries1:
        with open(entry, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                if name1 in line:
                    outs3 = os.path.join(path, 'newbatterystat.txt')
                    sys.stdout = open(outs3, 'a')
                    print(entry + '\n', line)
                if strt in line:
                    outs3 = os.path.join(path, 'newbatterystat.txt')
                    sys.stdout = open(outs3, 'a')
                    print(entry + '\n', line)
```

The output is filename, reset time and plug=ac.
It appears that the IF IN construction does not take more then 1 variable.